# Using the word “Triumphant”

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Let’s say the outcome of focusing on quality over quantity produced a better result. Is it correct to say that “Quality is still the **triumphant factor** of ensuring consumer’s trust”?

Comment: What did your dictionary say about "triumphant"?  Quote the definition which you are using for your example.

Comment: It sounds a bit odd, but saying "quality triumphs over other factors" would be unobjectionable, so I don't think it's wrong, merely unusual.

Comment: Plus, change “of” to “in”

Answer (score 3):

As [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20still%20the%20%2A%20factor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cis%20still%20the%20%2A%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20dominant%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20controlling%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20major%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20limiting%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20main%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20determining%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20dominating%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20decisive%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20chief%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20deciding%20factor%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cis%20still%20the%20*%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20dominant%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20controlling%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20major%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20limiting%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20main%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20determining%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20dominating%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20decisive%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20chief%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20still%20the%20deciding%20factor%3B%2Cc0) shows...

[image]

...common terms with near-synonymous meanings in the sequence *[Some factor] **is still the** [adjective] **factor** [affecting some situation or judgement]* include ***dominant, main, major, determining, decisive, dominating, deciding, controlling***.

But ***triumphant*** isn't in that list, because it doesn't really make sense. To be "triumphant" normally requires that the subject be some kind of "conscious entity", rather than simply some factor to be taken into account.